# Wordpress MySQL Syntax Error

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm having this MySQL error:

WordPress database error:

> [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
> server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1]
>
> SELECT file_name FROM art_uploaded_files WHERE file_number in()

here's the php line:

```
$file_name=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT file_name FROM art_uploaded_files WHERE file_number in(".substr($_files_id,0,-1).")");
```

I'm using this for php upload file.

Comment: can you print out what is the result of `"SELECT file_name FROM art_uploaded_files WHERE file_number in(".substr($_files_id,0,-1).")"`

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because `$_file_id` is empty.

So your query resulted to this:

```
SELECT file_name FROM art_uploaded_files WHERE file_number in()
```

Pay attention to the error message.

to work your query is supposed to look like this:

```
SELECT file_name FROM art_uploaded_files WHERE file_number in(1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: @lbu i did use that query still having the same problem. i'm able to upload files but cant write to the database i even set the privileges to "allow" and chmod to 777

Comment: @user1840983 i see my first attempt was kind of confusing, see my update